# Python regex slow when whitespace in string

Tags: python, regex

I would like to match strings, using Pythons regex module.

In my case I want to verify that strings start, end and consist of upper case letters combined by "_". As an example, the following string is valid: "MY_HERO2". The following strings are not valid: "_MY_HREO2", "MY HERO2", "MY_HERO2_"

To validate a string I use this code:

```
import re
my_string = "MY_HERO"   

p = re.compile("^([A-Z,0-9]+_??)+[A-Z,0-9]$")
if p.match(my_string):
    print "validated"
```

So what is my problem? Validating long string containing whitespaces is very, very slow. How can I avoid this? Is my pattern wrong? What is the reason for this behavior?

Here are some numbers:

```
MY_HERO2 --> 53 ms
MY_SUPER_GREAT_UNBELIEVABLE_HERO --> 69 microseconds
MY_SUPER_GREAT_UNBELIEVABLE HERO --> 223576 microseconds
MY_SUPER_GREAT_UNBELIEVABLE_STRONG_HERO --> 15 microseconds
MY_SUPER_GREAT_UNBELIEVABLE_STRONG HERO --> 979429 microseconds
```

Thanks for your anwsers and responses in advance. :-)
Paul

Comment: The string can't start or end with an underscore ? and why are you using commas `,` in your character classes, are they allowed ?

Comment: Looks like a case of evil backtracking.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> So what is my problem?

The problem is [catastrophic backtracking](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html). The regex engine is trying a whole lot of variations which is taking a lot of time.

Let's try this with a pretty simple example: `A_B D`.

The engine first matches `A` with `[A-Z,0-9]+` then it now tries `_??` but since it is optional *(lazy)* it skips it for now, and this has finished `([A-Z,0-9]+_??)+`.

Now the engine tries to match `[A-Z,0-9]` but there is a `_` in the string so it fails and now it needs to backtrack, so it re-enters `([A-Z,0-9]+_??)+` where it failed the last time and tries `_??` and succeeds.

Now the engine exits `([A-Z,0-9]+_??)+` again and tries to match `[A-Z,0-9]` and it succeeds, then it tries to match end-of-string `$` but fails, now it backtracks and enters `([A-Z,0-9]+_??)+` again.

I hope you see where this is going as I am tiered of writing it and we haven't reached the space character yet *-actually any character not accepted in your regex such as `#` or `%`, etc will cause this, not just the whitespace-* and this is a small tiny example, in the case of your long strings, it will have to do this hundreds and hundreds of times until it is able to match the entire string or fails, hence the great amount of time.

> Validating long string containing whitespaces is very, very slow.

Again this due to backtracking and hell of variations.

> How can I avoid this?

You can use this regex instead:

```
^([A-Z0-9]_?)*[A-Z0-9]$
```

This ensures the string starts with an uppercase or number followed by an optional `_`, repeat this one or more times and just make sure there is an uppercase or a number at the end.

> Is my pattern wrong? What is the reason for this behavior?

Your expression is not wrong, but it is highly inefficient.

```
([A-Z,0-9]+_??)+[A-Z,0-9]$
          ^  ^ ^
        You  |see those two, they are a lot of trouble together 
             |
            These two ?? with the the other two + on the inside and outside, hell :)
```

Comment: Thanks for the very helpful response! I definetly need to dig deeper into this topic! Thanks also for the link!

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the same result using this simple regex:

```
import timeit

stmt = '''
import re
reg = '^(?:[A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9_]*)?[A-Z0-9]$'
p = re.compile(reg)
p.match('%s')
'''

str_list = ['MY_HERO2', 'MY_SUPER_GREAT_UNBELIEVABLE_HERO', 'MY_SUPER_GREAT_UNBELIEVABLE HERO', 'MY_SUPER_GREAT_UNBELIEVABLE_STRONG_HERO', 'MY_SUPER_GREAT_UNBELIEVABLE_STRONG HERO']

for s in str_list:
    t = timeit.timeit(stmt%s, number=1000)
    print '%s: %s' % (s, t)

import re
reg = '^(?:[A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9_]*)?[A-Z0-9]$'
p = re.compile(reg)
for s in str_list:
    result = p.match(s) is not None
    print '%s: %s' % (s, result)
```

Results:

```
MY_HERO2: 0.00375986099243
MY_SUPER_GREAT_UNBELIEVABLE_HERO: 0.00417900085449
MY_SUPER_GREAT_UNBELIEVABLE HERO: 0.00534510612488
MY_SUPER_GREAT_UNBELIEVABLE_STRONG_HERO: 0.00419306755066
MY_SUPER_GREAT_UNBELIEVABLE_STRONG HERO: 0.00567102432251

MY_HERO2: True
MY_SUPER_GREAT_UNBELIEVABLE_HERO: True
MY_SUPER_GREAT_UNBELIEVABLE HERO: False
MY_SUPER_GREAT_UNBELIEVABLE_STRONG_HERO: True
MY_SUPER_GREAT_UNBELIEVABLE_STRONG HERO: False
```